# Python definition function and for range() loop

Tags: python, rounding, mathematical-optimization

I have a defined function:

```
def micronToStep(v):
    #approximately 62nm/step
    return round((v * 1000)/62)
```

And the command `for range()` loop:

```
xyStep = 5
xRange = 400

for x in range(-micronToStep(xRange/2), micronToStep(xRange/2) - micronToStep(xyStep), micronToStep(xyStep))
```

For `xyStep = 5`, `xRange = 400` the command: `len(range(-micronToStep(xRange/2), micronToStep(xRange/2) - micronToStep(xyStep), micronToStep(xyStep)))` returns `79`, which not exceed the limit `xRange/xyStep = 80`.

But for `xyStep = 1`, `xRange = 400` the `len(range())` function returns incorrect value `403` instead of value less or equal to `xRange/xyStep = 400`.

I think the problem lies in `micronToStep()` function.

How to correct this, that `for range()` loop would not exceed the limit of xRange/xyStep by number of iterations?

Comment: The issue is with your rounding. `micronToStep(1)` returns 16 but the unrounded value is 16.129. Are you sure it's appropriate to round like this? It might make sense to round the values returned by your range, but rounding the step in your range can affect how many elements you get, as you have seen here.

Comment: You also need to insure that ```micronToStep``` is guaranteed to return an`` int```, since ```range``` requires ```int``` values.

Comment: Maybe you want `ceil()` rather than `round()`, so it will round up from 16.129 to 17.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain what it is you are trying to do.  I believe the purpose of the ```micronToStep``` is to define the number of micron increments compose a step, and it seems that you are trying to create steps which fall in the range ```-xrange/2``` to ```+xrange/2``` in steps defined by ```xystep```.  Is this correct?

Comment: @joanis How to properly round in function `microToStep` to get appropriate values?

Comment: @itprorh66 Yes, it is correct what you've written.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  When I run the code i get a length of 79 steps ranging in value from -3226 to 3092.  If this is incorrect, can you explain what you consider to be correct?

Comment: @itprorh66 This is correct what you've written 79 is smaller than 80. The incorrect value is for `xyStep = 1` because it gives 403 instead of something equal to 400 or smaller.

Comment: You've assumed that equal sized steps is desirable. For example, if you want the values from 1 to 7 (inclusive), in 5 steps total, you'd need steps of 1.5; `1.0, 2.5, 4.0, 5.5, 7.0`. But if you want integer values what result do you want? `1, 3, 4, 6, 7` has unequal step sizes, and  neither `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7` nor `1, 3, 5, 7` have 5 steps total. Until you define the behaviour you prefer, there is no answer, just an observation of your faulty assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can solve your problem as follows:

```
xyStep = 1
xrange = 400
[micronStep(x) for x in range(xrange//2, (xrange//2 - xyStep), xyStep]
```

This yields a list of length 399, and additionally simplifies the computation, since micronToStep is only called once for each step.

Comment: This is an excellent idea, build the range over steps and then convert to microns.

Comment: Your code does not actually work as it stands, though, with the extra `for` at the beginning, a missing closing parenthesis, and the logic not quite right, but the approach is good.

Comment: Please note, I am just repeating the code sample provided by the OP, since I have no idea of the context of how it is being used, nor any indication that there was an error in it's operation, I felt that was the best way to respond to the question

Comment: I'm not asking you to fix all of OP's logic, but it is worth actually testing code you provide in answers here to at least make sure it runs. This code does not run due to several syntax errors. You also claim "this yields a list of length 399", but it does not. I'd like to upvote your answer because of the idea itself, but I'd want to be able to cut and paste your answer and see it work first.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, I did test the code but in copying over, I made an error which I didn't catch previously.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that using `ceil()` instead of `round()` in `micronToStep()` function works pretty good but I think it's not an optimal solution.